# How to sync iPhone contacts to Gmail and update them on in-use Android phone

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, gmail

I've recently moved from Android (Nexus 5x) to iPhone. Added Gmail account and synced all contacts from Android to iPhone.

I'm using both the iPhone and Nexus.

Now I've added a few more contacts on iPhone, but it doesn't show when the contacts are synced to Gmail.
I want these to reflect on my Nexus device as well, since the same Gmail account is logged into it.

What I'm exactly looking for is a link between iPhone and Nexus.
Is there a way I can sync the updated contacts from my iPhone to Gmail account, so that Gmail has all updated info. Then I want these updated contacts to show up in my Android device as well.

Comment: You're probably adding the Contacts to your iCloud accounts instead of to your Gmail account (which is a struggle on iOS). Go to Settings -> iCloud and turn of Contacts for iCloud on your iPhone. Then in Accounts settings on your iPhone, make sure Contacts is on for your Gmail account, then contacts should automatically be added to your gmail account and synced to your 5X as well.

Comment: Happy to help! I posted this as an answer, you can accept it with the checkmark button :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sync contacts with your Android phone, you need to make sure that you're adding the contacts to your Gmail account on your iPhone rather than to your iCloud account.

1. Turn on Contacts syncing with your Gmail account by going to Settings -> Mail, Contacts and Calendars -> your Gmail account -> turn on Contacts.
2. Turn off Contacts syncing with any other account there.
3. Turn off iCloud contacts syncing by going to Settings -> iCloud -> turn off Contacts.

---

Now, when you add contacts on your iPhone, they should automatically sync with your Nexus 5X over Google's servers.

**Note:** If you lose any contacts you added previously on your iPhone, have no fear, they're still accessible at [icloud.com](https://iCloud.com) and you can [export them as a vCard](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph3606?locale=en_US) and open up that file on your iPhone to sync them with your phones as well.